# Unable to pull whatsapp number using BeautifulSoup in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm new in python i'm pulling some datas. I want to pull the whatsapp number using regular expressions.

here is my code :

```
from textwrap import shorten
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests
import re

url = 'https://m.propertyfinder.ae/en/rent/apartment-for-rent-dubai-dubai-marina-marina-promenade-delphine-tower-7276805.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
whatsapp_script = all_scripts[6]
whatsapp = re.search('{"type":"whatsapp","value":"([^"]+)"[^}]+}', whatsapp_script)

print(whatsapp.group())
```

I'm getting error like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evilslab/Documents/Websites/www.futurepoint.dev.cc/dobuyme/python/fetchFinder.py", line 12, in <module>
    whatsapp = re.search('{"type":"whatsapp","value":"([^"]+)"[^}]+}', whatsapp_script)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 199, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How i can pull the whatsapp number from the source data ?

Comment: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"
It seems to me like you are passing a regex over an object, not over text.

>soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
>soup = str(soup)

Should stringify the result.

Comment: Great it worked :) but the output is now like ('+971566809258',)
How to get absolute number ?

Answer (score 1):

`whatsapp_script` is of type `bs4.element.Tag`. Try to use its `.text` attribute:

```
print(re.search('{"type":"whatsapp","value":"([^"]+)"[^}]+}', whatsapp_script.text))
```

Outputs

```
<re.Match object; span=(39851, 40276), match='{"type":"whatsapp","value":"+971566809258","link">
```

And to get the actual number (the match from the regex), use the `.group(1)` attribute:

```
print(re.search('{"type":"whatsapp","value":"([^"]+)"[^}]+}', whatsapp_script.text).group(1))
```

Outputs

```
+971566809258
```

Comment: Yes it worked :), then what is difference between using groups and group ?

Comment: @sonu_rdx `groups()` returns a tuple of all the matched groups. `group(N)` returns the match of the group `N`

Comment: without using group we can't access data ?

Comment: But u know when i try to pull from some more pages with a loop it produce AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @sonu_rdx please do some self research. `re.search` will return `None` if your regex does not find anything, then `re.search(..).group` will raise the `AttributeError` you saw

Comment: That means some thing changes in that web page right ?